# Combining stored procedure statement causes error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I use the query individually then it works. But it fails when I combine both the stored procedure statements.

`spMarkAsApproved` is a stored procedure with an `Update` statement.

This works

```
spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A';
```

This also works

```
spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';
```

But this doesn't work

```
spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A';
spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'spMarkAsApproved'.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: `exec spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A'; exec spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';`

Comment: If you are calling a procedure without using `EXEC` it *must* be the **first** statement in the batch.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's not necessary to specify the `EXECUTE` keyword when the statement is the first one in a batch. But you may try with `EXEC spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A'; EXEC spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) if you are calling a procedure and it is the *first* statement in the batch, then the `EXEC` keyword can be omitted:

> #### Remarks
>
> ...
> You do not have to specify the EXECUTE keyword when executing modules if the statement is the first one in a batch.
>
> #### Examples: SQL Server
>
> ...
> If the following is the first statement in a batch or an **osql** or **sqlcmd** script, EXEC is not required.
>
> ```sql
> dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers 6;  
> GO  
> --Or  
> dbo.uspGetEmployeeManagers @EmployeeID = 6;  
> GO
> ```

If the statement is therefore *not* the first statement, then `EXEC` *must* be used.

Your second statement is not the *first* statement, so `EXEC` must be used:

```
spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A';
EXEC spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';
```

Better yet, if I am honest, always use `EXEC(UTE)`:

```sql
EXEC spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A';
EXEC spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';
```

Answer (score 2):

A stored procedure can be called and executed without the EXEC keyword if the procedure is the first statement in the Transact-SQL batch.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16

```
exec spMarkAsApproved '112', 'A';
exec spMarkAsApproved '113', 'A';
```